# Kotlin CoroutineDispatcher creates additional thread instead of rethrowing RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Here's an example:

```
// max 1 pending task in queue
val queue = LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1)
// max 1 thread / 1 active task 
val executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue)

val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
fun run() {
    val millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
    val thread = Thread.currentThread().name
    println("executing after $millis ms on thread $thread")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
}

executor.execute { run() }
executor.execute { run() }
// executor.execute { run() } // RejectedExecutionException, ok

Thread.sleep(10_000)

val job = SupervisorJob()
val dispatcher = executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
    println("never invoked")
}

val scope = CoroutineScope(job + dispatcher + exceptionHandler)

scope.launch { run() }
scope.launch { run() }
scope.launch { run() } // !
```

The last line causes a new thread to be created instead of throwing `RejectedExecutionException` (or invoking `exceptionHandler`):

executing after 3 ms on thread pool-1-thread-1
executing after 3006 ms on thread pool-1-thread-1
executing after 10063 ms on thread pool-1-thread-1
executing after 10079 ms on thread kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor
executing after 13066 ms on thread pool-1-thread-1

The code above should fail in case the queue is full, but I see no way to implement it with Kotlin coroutines properly: using a custom `RejectedExecutionHandler` to throw a different exception helps to achieve the desired behavior but violates `Executor`/`RejectedExecutionHandler` contract and may just break other code instead.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dispatcher` is not an `Executor` and has a very different contract and purpose. Especially, it is not an option to fail to dispatch the resumption of a coroutine.

In analogy to Java threads, it would be equivalent to `Thread.destroy()`, which makes the thread disappear without a trace. No `finally` blocks get executed, no `synchronized` blocks get exited from, because the thread doesn't experience any exception that makes it complete. `Thread.destroy()` has been removed from Java for a very good reason.

Note that there's no user code you can throw the `RejectedExecutionException` to. You have a very narrow special case where the coroutines don't suspend at all, they just get started. This is the only reason your analogy to task submission seems reasonable.